# Match whole world regular expression with multiple strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a regular expression with a string. My objective is to find the word is in the following sentence. But i need to find only the index of the words at position 5, 25 and 48. But the expression is returning. The "is" present in "This" too. What am i doing wrong?

```
var re = /(is)\b/gi,
str = "This,is a nice job. This is, a nice world. What is this?";
while((match = re.exec(str)) != null){
console.log(match.index);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to match the word boundary on both ends

```
var re = /\b(is)\b/gi
```